# Use a GET variable to see a referrer in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, php, url, drupal

I have a system on my site that sends an email to a customer with a certain url in it (not a private url, just the info they've requested). The format of this url is just straight on:

```
http://www.mysite.com/the/requested/data
```

When the user clicks on this url, Google Analytics sees this as 'Direct' traffic. However, I also have a lot of 'real' direct traffic, users that just type the url, or use bookmarks, and I need to distinguish these 'mailed' users from the rest.

I was thinking about this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/the/requested/data?ref=mail
```

and then in the frontend (a Drupal 7 site), capture this GET variable ref, and if it is set to mail, then call the Javascript to trigger a Google Analytics Event.

Is this the only way to go about? Or are there other/better ways?
Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the answer you are looking for on Google's support page for Analytics.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033173?hl=en

Click on the bottom link that reads **Custom Campaigns**  and I bet that you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, looks very good indeed! Do you have any experience with this? Will Google Analytics indeed automatically pick up these variables?

Comment: From what I've read up on there shouldn't be much issues with migrating. And yes Analytics should pick up these variables. I suggest posting on the mailing list for Analytics. Or try IRC.